# Android layout 480dpi support

Tags: android

How to make layout to support 480dpi as well as other dpi. Current devices like htc one m8 , samsung galaxy edge are of 480 dpi. But how to create separate layout folder for 480dpi is not mentioned. Thanks in advance.

@Frank N. Stein layout-xlarge is not for 480 dpi

Comment: You can make one layout only for 480dpi and check programatically if device has 480 dpi then set that layout.

Comment: @KishuDroid Please note that **480 dpi** is nothing but **xxhdpi**.

Comment: what should be layout folder name ?

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need to know is [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Comment: this documentation is not helpful.